# AttributeError: module 'face_recognition' has no attribute 'load_image_file'

Tags: python, face-recognition

I have succefully installed a library to perform face recognition; I have tried to use this on a program but I get an attribute **error**.

```py
# Import the face_recognition library
import face_recognition
import face_recognition_models

# Load a sample image
image = face_recognition.load_image_file(r'C:\Users\WAJIH\Desktop\code\face')

# Detect faces in the image
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model="cnn")

# Print the number of faces detected
print(f"{len(face_locations)} faces detected")
```

out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "c:\Users\WAJIH\Desktop\Face-recognition-python-project-main\ss.py", line 1, in 
import face_recognition
File "C:\Users\WAJIH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\face_recognition_*init*_.py", line 7, in 
from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
File "C:\Users\WAJIH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 3, in 
import PIL.Image
File "C:\Users\WAJIH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL_*init*_.py", line 15, in 
from . import _version
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. read the docs of the library you are trying to use. it says the function name does not exist.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/318

Comment: By the way you don't need to do that _ import face_recognition_models_ manually.